# Clang C2 on Visual studio 15.5 bool_constant<__is_trivially_destructible(_Ty)> error : '_Ty' does not refer to a value

Tags: visual-studio, clang

I am trying to re-compile a hello world using Clang_C2 compiler on Visual studio 15.5 (latest).

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\type_traits(899,2): error : expected class name
1>        {       // determine whether _Ty has a trivial destructor

In file included from ..\hello_boost_exception\hello_boost_exception.cpp:11:
1>In file included from I:\modular-boost\boost/config.hpp:48:
1>In file included from I:\modular-boost\boost/config/stdlib/dinkumware.hpp:98:
1>In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\typeinfo:22:
1>In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\exception:7:
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\type_traits(898,47):
```

This looks as though I have some missing or incorrect library but I can't see what.

I have try various compiler versions C++14 (-std=c++1y) and library -stdlib=libc++ (should it use dinkumware version of type_traits?) but the error persists.

Suggestions most welcome.

Paul

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. It was working just fine until I updated to 15.5 this morning.

Comment: Reported as https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162874/vs-155-e1027-language-modes-specified-are-incompat.html

Comment: To roll back to v15.0 (most intermediate versions are missing) uninstall Visual Studio, then download (login required) from: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%2015.2&pgroup=